# How to query for an empty string in PHP Mongo?

Tags: php, mongodb

I'd like to query for all documents in my collection where the field `client` is an empty string. I've seen plenty of examples of how to check if something's not an empty string but I can't find any examples of how to do the opposite. I've tried `db.collection.find({client: ""})` but I get back an empty set.

EDIT: The example entry in the collection looks like

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("54eb59699e12a795078b80da"), "reportID" : "1472031", "orgID" : "336", "client" : "", "customerID" : NumberLong(1), "address" : "123 main st", "city" : "Grove City", "state" : "OH", "zip" : "43123", "county" : "Franklin", "gpsLatitude" : null, "gpsLongitude" : null, "dateDue" : ISODate("2012-08-18T00:00:00Z"), "dateDueClient" : ISODate("2012-08-18T00:00:00Z"), "dateComplete" : ISODate("2012-08-18T00:00:00Z"), "dateCompleteEstimate" : NumberLong(0), "contractorSubmissionDate" : ISODate("2012-08-19T00:26:23Z"), "createdOn" : ISODate("2012-08-19T00:21:37Z"), "assignedToContractorOn" : ISODate("2012-08-19T00:21:37Z"), "workTypeID" : "6338", "assignedAdmin" : "7880", "contractorID" : "7880", "categoryID" : "0", "historyLength" : NumberLong(0), "invoiceDate" : ISODate("2012-08-18T00:00:00Z"), "submittedToClient" : ISODate("2012-08-18T00:00:00Z"), "paymentContractor" : NumberLong(0), "paymentClient" : NumberLong(0), "contractorIsPaid" : NumberLong(0), "clientIsPaid" : NumberLong(0), "sentinel" : NumberLong(1), "isFrozen" : NumberLong(0), "numTimesClientReady" : "1", "pcrResponses" : [ ] }
```

There's a lot of fields but the client one is pretty close to the beginning.

Comment: That should work fine. Can you show us a sample document that you'd like to match, but fail to match?

Comment: It's a syntax error so the format of the document shouldn't matter in regards to the syntax error

Comment: You said it was an empty result, not a syntax error, in the original question. If it's a syntax error, please post the code and the error. The query on `{ "client" : "" }` works fine with that document. It's in mongo shell syntax, though. Is it PHP code that's not working? Can you show us the PHP code?

Comment: sorry for the ambiguity. I got an empty result from `db.collection.find({"client": ""})` and I got a syntax error from `db.collection.find({'client':{'$in':{'',array(),null,0}}})`. I'm not to the point of putting this into PHP code yet. I'm still just trying to get it to work in the mongo shell

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The query you posted should work. Just to verify, I inserted that data as a row in a test collection, and it was returned right back out with `db.test.find({client: ''})`

I'm thinking you may have a problem somewhere else. I've once or twice been in the wrong database when running queries, or had a typo in the collection name. To verify what my data looks like, I'll often times:

```
> db.tset.find({client: ''});
[] // What? No results? ...backspacebackspacebackspace

> db.tset.find();
[] // What? No results at all for no query? I must be in the.. OH!

> db.test.find();
[] // What? I thought I had a typo in my collection name. What database am I in?

> db
tseting // OH! I keep making that typo..

> use testing
switched to db testing

> db.test.find({client: ''});
[] // What? Still no results? This is weird...

> db.test.insert({client: ''});

> db.test.find({client: ''});
{ "_id" : ObjectId("54f1b5e5d05052fce4fb6684"), "client" : "" }
// Hmm, ok, so there's nothing wrong with the query. The data came up
// So I'm still just in the wrong place? Really?
// Maybe I woke up on the wrong side of the bed today. I should eat lunch.
```

Sometimes tunnel vision makes you think the problem lies somewhere that it doesn't. Leave a comment if this is or isn't helpful, maybe we can come up with some more troubleshooting ideas.

Comment: It's not related to being in the wrong collection or any typos but I think that maybe my documentation regarding what empty entries look like is wrong. I don't think that it's an empty string.

Comment: Perhaps do a `var x = db.collection.findOne({_id: ObjectId("54eb59699e12a795078b80da")});` and then `typeof x.client`, see what it returns?